# Hide the icons on the Mac OS X Launchpad without modify the DB?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, info.plist

Is there any way to hide the icons on OS X's Launchpad?

As I know, Launchpad will scan all of the app under the`/Applications` folder , and generate the icons automatically.

The information stores in `~/Library/Application Support/Dock/*.db`

Is there any way to remove the icons on the Launchpad without modify  `~/Library/Application Support/Dock/*.db`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some survey, I think there has no good solution for this problem (At least in Mac OS X 10.9).

But I found two workaround,

1. Rename your app : If your app naming include "uninstall", the Launchpad will ignore your app (eg: ***myappuninstall.app***).
2. Use the **LSUIElement** or **LSBackgroundOnly** properity in your app's *Info.plist*, and put your app under second layer of the **/Applications** subfolder (eg: ***/Applications/yourfolder/secondfolder/your.app***).

Note: Apple customize Launchpad behavior for some app such as "Adobe Application Manager.app", Launchpad will not generate the icons if app use some specific CFBundleIdentifier (eg: “com.adobe.PDApp” from [Adobe Application Manager.app]).